# How to assign default value to ansible ARRAY variable

Tags: arrays, variables, ansible, default

i have an array user_names like below:

Note: The array "user_names" may have zero or more entries depending on the task "Register username"

Incase, "user_names" is empty I wish to assign and print "Not Applicable" message else I wish to print the array.

I use "listusers" variable and default() method for this purpose. However, printing listusers.results, listusers.stdout both throw error for "listusers" variable and I'm not sure how to do this.

```
tasks:    
- name: Set default values
  tags: always
  set_fact:
    user_names: []

- name: Register username
 tags: stop,start
  set_fact:
    user_names: "{{ user_names + [item.stdout] | unique }}"
  when: item.rc == 0
  with_items:
    - "{{ curr_user_ids.results }}"

- name: Status 
  tags: always,status
  set_fact:
    listusers: "{{ user_names | default('Not Applicable') }}
```

This works for non-Array variables but for array variable I'm not sure of a solution.

Can you please suggest ?

Comment: can you show the output of task  Register username

Comment: @sebthebert: i have reposted the query with the output here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58761776/unable-to-assign-default-value-to-ansible-registered-variable-based-on-condition

Answer (score 0):

> This works for non-Array variables but for array variable I'm not sure of a solution.

The thing you are looking for is [`user_names | union([item.stdout])`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters)

```
- name: Register username
 tags: stop,start
  set_fact:
    user_names: "{{ user_names | union([item.stdout]) }}"
```

As you can see, a pleasing side-effect of `union` is that it also automatically makes the resulting `list` unique, since it is a `set` operation